# Want to revert back my pushed commit from main repository

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

I'm facing i want to remove my commit from main repository. the code has pushed with my unwanted local changes. So how can i revert back that. i'm using source tree and git as well. please help me.

Comment: Move your local master to the right location and push -f.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [`git revert`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert). It doesn't change history, but "unmakes" a single commit by applying the reverse actions to the source as a new commit.

You can specify a range of commits for `revert` with the `..` syntax ([detailed explanation](http://git-scm.com/book/it/v2/Git-Tools-Revision-Selection)):

```
git revert -n abcd1234..fedc0987
```

(The `n` flag prevents autocommits. `abcd...` stands for a unique commit ID hash.)

Comment: what is that abcd124 means? is that means commit id?

Comment: Oh, those are commit identifier hashes. By using `git log` in the terminal you can see the unique hash for each and every commit in the Git repo. On Source Tree there should be unique hashes in each commit's info somewhere I presume. I used `abcd...` as an example.

Comment: Yes, the unique commit id hash.

Comment: Commit: f6341b46f76ddc1d6a7d2b387f780a101d7850a8  .... are u mentioning this?

Comment: fine thanks. will it remove my changes from main repo?

Comment: It will remove the commit changes from the branch you're on. If the commit doesn't exist on a certain branch, the `revert` will not work. Once the command is executed, just push the new commit (result of `revert`) to the main repo and it will act like any normal commit. The good side of this is a that `revert` doesn't undo history so your team members can use the new commit without headaches.

Comment: won't it be affected the other commits after commited mine?

Comment: Yes and no. Yes as in others can undo the changes of your undo-commit (which used `revert`). No as in `revert` prevents conflicts in history and content.

Comment: @ojrask For a detailed explanation for the "range of commits" syntax (`..`) take a look at [this chapter](http://git-scm.com/book/it/v2/Git-Tools-Revision-Selection) from the progit book. I've also edited the answer with the reference.